# Json not parsing \n as new line from third party API

Tags: node.js, json, regex, express

What I am trying to do is get new line from response that I am getting from third party api and route it onto my end. Problem is that I am getting \n instead of new line for each response.

This is related to a school project I am doing but I am really bad at this

I am not really savvy when it comes escaping characters and all my attempts have failed.

This is a part of code responsible for fetching data

```
const Dota2API = require('dota2-web-api');
const express = require("express");
const dota2API = new Dota2API('80CAC0AD297459DA36B70FD4365AEDD6', 'en_us');


const router = express.Router();


router.get('', (req, res, next) => {
    let KKona;
    dota2API.getLiveLeagueGames( function(r) {
        console.log(r);
        KKona = r;
        res.json(KKona);
    })
});



module.exports = router;
```

**EXAMPLE RESPONSE:**

```
"{\n\"result\":{\n\"games\":[\n{\n\"players\":[\n{\n\"account_id\":307718596,\n\"name\":\"Осталось не долго\",\n\"hero_id\":9,\n\"team\":0\n},\n{\n\"account_id\":986933106,\n\"name\":\"Поросёнок228\",\n\"hero_id\":72,\n\"team\":1\n},\n{\n\"account_id\":352733459,\n\"name\":\"ками-\",\n\"hero_id\":94,\n\"team\":1\n},\n{\n\"account_id\":226243143,\n\"name\":\"youth\",\n\"hero_id\":9
```

Receive that same data with new line instead of \n

Comment: can you post an example response? `\n`is already the representation of a new line, and this should be handled by whoever is using the response.

Comment: @ViniciusPinto yeah, gonna update post in a second

Comment: I thought the `\n`was in the value of one of the JSON fields. In this case, Dean answer's should do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The output of `getLiveLeagueGames`, the value of `r` is of type `string`

You can see this by including the line:

```
console.log(typeof r)
```

You are then passing that to `res.json` which is processing the string into JSON.

Consider either parsing the string into an object (`JSON.parse`) or passing the response directly out.

Also note don't share your API keys / secrets publicly.

Comment: Oh my god I didn't even notice api key, this coulda have compromised my steam account, already revoked it.

Comment: @pepega also note I would usually expect the result to be of type `object` from a library like this, it might be a case were there is a bug in the `dota2-web-api` library. Check the documentation, report a bug if needed.